# Do UIButtons' properties stay when put into an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, uibutton, swift2

I was wondering if when I put a UIButton into an array like this:

```
var array:[UIButton] = [UIButton]()
```

would the buttons tags, titles, images and other values be put into the array?
When the UIButton is appended, will the properties' values stay under the UIButton at the index that was appended?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All properties of the buttons would remain the same because you're not changing the buttons or their properties. Instead, you're just grouping the buttons into an array.